# Access Form Macro Where Condition

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

This is my first post here. Kind of a newbie at Access and I've searched forums to answer my question and tried using similar answers to get my macro working, but I have a syntax error.

I want to click the `details` button on one form (`Employee Profile`), and open another form (`Employee Training Records`) where it will pull up records pertaining to the current employee profile.

In my where condition currently I have:

```
="[st_no]=" & [st_no] & " AND [emp_id]='" & [emp_id] & "'"
```

I get a syntax error saying:

> (missing operator) in query expression '[st_no]=IEC 62841-2-5 AND [emp_id]='3"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since the field `st_no` looks to be a string, you'll need to enclose the corresponding value with single or double quotes; conversely, since `emp_id` looks to be an integer, you don't need the surrounding quotes.

As such, I would suggest:

```
="[st_no]='" & [st_no] & "' AND [emp_id]=" & [emp_id]
```

Comment: @JessicaRadliff You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!